# Objects in scene continue to be dark after lighting is set up

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

***Here is how my scene is currently looking:***

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I had previously set up this scene to be dark although I don't exactly remember how I did that. Now I'm trying to set the scene as a daytime one. **Despite putting a directional light with a strong intensity, the objects I made for the scene continue to be dark**. So I'm at a standstill here. I've only been using Unity since February.

Edit: Added Lighting Settings for the scene.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an ambient light source? Do you need to bake your lighting? Show us a  screenshot of your Light Settings tab.

Comment: I did not. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Your 'Auto Generate' option is deselected. If you press Generate Lighting does it bake correctly?

Comment: For some reason it did not last night. But now it actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: I left an answer, based on your findings! Glad it you got it working. Looks like an interesting scene from your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks. I've been working on everything since February since I started using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

In your Light Settings tab, either select the `Auto Generate` checkbox or click the `Generate Lighting` button to properly bake your light.

Answer (score 0):

Two Possible problems and their solution:

1. If you don't want bake, then go in lighting tab and **clear** baked data.
2. Ensure that Lighting is on at editor, see below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because the "Sun Source" variable in the Lighting window was set to "None". Grabbing my Directional Light from the scene in there solved the problem.

I hope this can help someone in the future.